# WSO2 Android Platform config returns An unexpected error occurred when trying to save

Tags: android, configuration, wso2

So i have been closely following the wso2 emm doco and can successfully login to the management and emm consoles. I've enabled GCM api however when i choose GCM, add the API key and sender id, paste in the EULA and click save i always get "An unexpected error occurred" and config is not saved, tailing the http logs i see:

> POST /mdm-android-agent/configuration HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1

following by

> POST /emm/api/invoker/execute/ HTTP/1.1 200 65

Where does this config get saved to ? 
Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u specify the EMM version and OS?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is saved to registry. If you use EMM standalone pack, it should be saved to "/_system/config/android"

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my issue for the moment, i commented out the security-constraint in mdm-android-agent/WEB-INF/web.xml so no more redirects and data is correctly saved.